# every 10 character/number combination

Tags: php, combinations

Ok I've been struggling for a while with this, tried using excel and other tools to generate every single 10 character/number combination possible, I decided I would try it with code? i tried it with javascript but cant seem to find any code that does this, I don't want any duplicates want it all to end in an .txt document. Ideally 1 output per line. Thanks in advance, I don't mind using other languages such as PHP but just need help :/ I have tried to do it in php my code Is below on my website. and then below that is what the code actually does. Thanks again, Steve.

Its not letting me post my code here so its on http://stephengoodings.com/combination/show.html

and it generates this http://stephengoodings.com/combination/

Comment: Your code looks correct, but consider the size of the output: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10+characters+from+36

Comment: if I'm not wrong, that would ouput an 2,758,547,353,515,625 lines file. What do you want to do with that? xDD

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite figure out your code, you say

> every single 10 character/number combination possible

and yet your code generates combinations of three symbols.

Anyway, I believe that the simpler way is to consider that you are using 36 symbols - A to Z, 0 to 9 - for each position in your sequence. If you had a *one* character sequence, that would give you 36 possibilities that you can number from 0 to 35.

If you had a *two* character sequence you'd get 36 possibilities for the first position and each of them could have 36 possibilities for the second, which gives 36 multiplied 36 (from 00 to 0A to 0Z, then A0, going on through ZZ) or 36 to the second power.

So if you have *ten* positions, you'll end up with 36 raised to the *tenth* power; each number from 0 to *that* number (minus 1) will uniquely identify one and only one combination. You just enumerate them all in a `for` cycle.

To do the reverse, to go from a number to a combination, you use modular arithmetic:

```
$symbols = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for ($i = 0; $i < BIG_NUMBER; $i++) {
    $start = $i;
    $seq   = '';
    for ($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
        $k = $start % strlen($symbols);
        $start /= strlen($symbols);
        $sq  .= $symbols[$k];  // or $seq = $symbol[$k] . $seq;
    }
    print "$seq\n";
}
```

Only be aware that 36 to the tenth power is 3656158440062976. While it *can* be held by a 64-bit number, it will take you a *very* long time to generate all combinations.

At one million combinations per second, I think that's around 115 years.

Also, eleven (ten characters and one newline) times 36 to the 10th is more than *thirty thousand* terabytes.

I think you'd better determine what you need that sequence for, and implement the problem differently.

For example: if you needed to brute-force a password in parallel, say between one hundred computers, you could assign to each computer a part of the sequence so as to have no duplication of efforts, and then have each of them attempt decoding and save the *current* combination being checked, instead of saving the past ones. Since the combinations are being enumerated in increasing order, and you know the start and end point for each system, you lose no information and obtain a huge saving in memory and disk space.